# What are "Active" bounties?

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to check one of my answers that I provided to a question with a bounty. So I checked my profile and noticed there is a bounties tab with 3 sub-tabs: "active", "offered", and "earned". I thought that my answer or question that I answered might be under "active" but there is nothing there. That got me wondering what that tab is for.

I assume that "offered" is for questions that I've added bounties to, and "earned" is for bounties I've earned. But what is "active" for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"active" is for bounties that you've offered *that are currently active*, meaning that can still be awarded to someone, and that have not already been awarded or expired..